# FirstOrDefault on ObservableCollection gets an ArgumentOutOfRange Exception

Tags: c#, linq

I've got an Observable Collection `CurrentItemSource` where I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when I try to call `FirstOrDefault` on it.

```
CommandViewModel item = CurrentItemSource?.FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't understand how this is possible since [this Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.1) describes that the only Exception that could be thrown from a `FirstOrDefault` is an `ArgumentNullException`.

The Exception I get:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException [2]: Der Index lag außerhalb des Bereichs. Er darf nicht negativ und kleiner als die Auflistung sein.
>     Parametername: index

How can that happen and are there any possibilities to fix this problem?

I instantiate the `CurrentItemSource` in the Constructor:

```
CurrentItemSource = new ObservableCollection<CommandViewModel>();

if (Application.Current != null)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
    { 
        CurrentItemSource.EnableCollectionSynchronization();
    }));
}
```

Then I also enable CollectionSynchronization to have a thread-safe ObservableCollection.

I also have a Binding in my XAML-File:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentItemSource}"/>
```

The Context of my `FirstOrDefault`-Call:

```
if (ComboBoxText.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    //Do Something
}
else
{
    CommandViewModel item = CurrentItemSource?.FirstOrDefault(); //Original Line

    if (item != null)
    {
        if (item is Type1)
        {
            //Do Something
        }
        else if (item is Type2)
        {
            //Do Something else
        }
    }   
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace [2]
       bei System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
       bei System.Collections.Generic.List1.get_Item(Int32 index)
       bei System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
       bei Gui.ViewModels.ComboBoxViewModel.SetDisplayedText(String comboBoxText) in D:\workspace\Gui\ViewModels\ComboBoxViewModel.cs:Zeile 707.
       bei Gui.ViewModels.ComboBoxViewModel.set_ComboBoxText(String value) in D:\workspace\Gui\ViewModels\ComboBoxViewModel.cs:Zeile 209.
       bei Gui.ViewModels.OutputViewModel.CreateContextMenu(ComboBoxViewModel comboBox) in D:\workspace\Gui\ViewModels\OutputViewModel.cs:Zeile 160.
       bei Gui.ViewModels.ComboBoxViewModel.CreateContextMenuAsync() in D:\workspace\Gui\ViewModels\ComboBoxViewModel.cs:Zeile 1051.
       bei Gui.ViewModels.ComboBoxViewModel.<BuildCurrentItemSource>b__135_0() in D:\workspace\Gui\ViewModels\ComboBoxViewModel.cs:Zeile 1031.
       bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
    --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
       bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       bei Gui.ViewModels.ComboBoxViewModel.<BuildCurrentItemSource>d__135.MoveNext() in D:\workspace\Gui\ViewModels\ComboBoxViewModel.cs:Zeile 1031.
```

Comment: What type is CurrentItemSource?

Comment: CurrentItemSource is an ObservableCollection<CommandViewModel>

Comment: do you have some more code arround? And the XAML file?

Comment: @SimonG Could you please post the code where you first instantiated the `CurrentItemSource` variable? Also, is this a multi-threaded application you are debugging?

Comment: I added more Code snippets, and yes it is a Multi-Threaded Application (@WaterCoolerv2)

Comment: @SimonG Thank you. Just one last thing. Please post the few lines before and after you call `FirstOrDefault` on the `CurrentItemSource` variable.

Comment: @SimonG And also the entire stack trace of the exception please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A brief summary of the cause for the exception**

Your code is throwing an exception because of thread-unsafe access to the underlying `IList<T>` that the `ObservableCollection` represents.

The [`EnableCollectionSynchronization`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization(v=vs.110).aspx) does not provide thread-safety of its own. It merely *guarantees that the `CustomView` will use the same synchronization technique for accessing the elements of the collection in a thread-safe manner as the one **you** provide*.

Note that the documentation reads:

> While you must synchronize your application's access to the
>   collection, you must also guarantee that access from WPF (specifically
>   from CollectionView) participates in the same synchronization
>   mechanism.  You do this by calling the EnableCollectionSynchronization
>   method.

**Solution**

Since you are using the [parameterless overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization(v=vs.110).aspx), you need to secure your access to the observable collection via a `lock` statement (or the `System.Threading.Monitor` class).

Therefore, you must do this:

```
// class level field
private object _lock = new object();

...

CommandViewModel item = null;

lock(_lock)
{
  item = CurrentItemSource?.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**More explanation about the cause of the exception**

The source of the exception is most likely one of the two following places. If you post the stack trace, you may see that it has in its path one of the two code paths:

**One: `System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<TSource>()`**

The `if` condition that checks for the nullability of the underlying list and then indexes.

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;

    // The following is re-entrant by multiple threads
    // in a thread-unsafe manner.
    if (list != null)
    {
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            // This code is contentious and most likely
            // the place where your code bombs.
            return list[0];
        }
    }
    else
        ...
```

**Two: In the `MoveNext` method of the `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>+Enumerator<T>` class**

Since you call the parameterless constructor of the `ObservableCollection` class, it defaults to using a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, which is thread-unsafe by default. And when any code that you or the WPF framework wrote `foreach`es over the collection, the `MoveNext` method of the `List<T>` class is called, which calls an implementation of the `MoveNext` method inside a private / nested class named `Enumerator<T>`. This may be another place where the thread-unsafe code could throw the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

```
public bool MoveNext()
{
    List<T> list = this.list;

    // This if condition might be entered into by a second thread
    // after the first thread modified the list
    if ((this.version == list._version) && (this.index < list._size))
    {
        // This line is contentious and might be
        // the source of your exception.
        this.current = list._items[this.index];


        this.index++;
        return true;
    }
    return this.MoveNextRare();
}
```

As you have now posted the stack trace, you see that it bombs off in the first of the two possible code paths I listed above. That is, in the `System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOfDefault` method body.

Comment: This was the Problem. Thank You for your detailed Explanation and your help.